# Java Regex - Split string on spaces - Ignore spaces in quotes and escaped quotes

Tags: java, regex, split, escaping, quote

I'm looking for regex to do the following in Java:

```
String originalString = "";
String splitString[] = originalString.spilt(regex);
```

Some test cases:

```
Original1: foo bar "simple"
Spilt1: { "foo", "bar", "\"simple\"" }

Original2: foo bar "harder \"case"
Spilt2: { "foo", "bar", "\"harder \"case\"" }

Original3: foo bar "harder case\\"
Spilt3: { "foo", "bar", "\"harder case\\"" }
```

Some snippets I have come across:

```
# Does not react to escaped quotes
 (?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)
# Finds relevant quotes that surround args
(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a question in there I'm not seeing?

Comment: @Andreas I'm looking for regex that will find the whitespaces that the strings need to be split on.

Comment: I voted to close your question as duplicate, but since pointed solution is not using `split` method but `Matcher#find` feel free to let me know if you didn't want to use it and want to have your question reopened for purely `split(regex)` solution.

Comment: @Pshemo The solution you linked works really well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String stringToSplit = This is the string to split;

String[] split = stringToSplit.split("character to split at");
```

In this case, `split[0]` would result as ' This ', `split[1]` would be ' is ', `split[2]` would be ' the ', `split[3]` ' string ' `split[4]` ' to ' `split[5]` ' split '.

At this point you can do

```
var0 = split[0];
var1 = split[1];
var2 = split[2];
```

Where `var0` would equal "This"
And so on...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that the first split piece is placed in the array as 0, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

Regex like this will work for simple cases:

```
("(.+?)(?<![^\\]\\)")|\S+
```

But I would not suggest to use RegEx for this task, but take a look at CSV parsers instead.